# Validação de dois campos com jQuery.validate e DataAnnotations

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery.validate

Boa tarde galera,

Seguinte, eu preciso validar se um de dois campos está preenchido, tentei criar uma função Attribute com ValidationAttribute mas não validou corretamente, acho que o jQuery.validate não a reconhece.

Segue os códigos:

Class ValidationAttribute

```
public class VerifyPhoneAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly string OtherPropertyName;

    public VerifyPhoneAttribute(string otherPropertyName)
        : base("Um dos telefones deve estar preenchido.")
    {
        OtherPropertyName = otherPropertyName;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(OtherPropertyName);
        string otherPhone = otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null).ToString(), thisDate = value.ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(otherPhone) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(thisDate))
            return new ValidationResult("Um dos telefones deve estar preenchido.");

        return null;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRegexRule(FormatErrorMessage(metadata.DisplayName), OtherPropertyName);

        return new List<ModelClientValidationRule>() { rule };
    }
}
```

Model

```
[MaxLength(15)]
    [Display(Name = "Primeiro telefone")]
    [VerifyPhone("client_phone2")]
    public string client_phone1 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(15)]
    [Display(Name = "Segundo telefone")]
    public string client_phone2 { get; set; }
```

View

```
<div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.client_phone1)
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.client_phone1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm input-phone input-phone1" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.client_phone1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.client_phone2)
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.client_phone2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-sm input-phone input-phone2" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.client_phone2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("VerifyPhone", "phone2");
    $.validator.addMethod("VerifyPhone", function (value, element, phone2) {
        return value.match(phone2);
    });
</script>
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe uma forma mais fácil de se fazer isso, que é utilizando o [IValidatableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

O `IValidatableObject` é uma interface que serve justamente para isso, valida obejtos.

Para utilizar, basta alterar o seu modelo para o seguinte:

```
//Adicione a interface IValidatableObject
public class Cliente : IValidatableObject
{
    [MaxLength(15)]
    [Display(Name = "Primeiro telefone")]
    public string client_phone1 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string client_phone2 { get; set; }

    //Aqui que a "mágica" ocorre
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(client_phone1) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(client_phone2))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Um dos telefones deve estar preenchido.", new[] { "client_phone1", "client_phone2" });
        }
    }
}
```

Note que na linha abaixo que adiciono a mensagem e em quais campos (`ValidationMessageFor()`) que a mensagem deve aparecer.

```
   yield return new ValidationResult("Um dos telefones deve estar preenchido.", new[] { "client_phone1", "client_phone2" });
```

Em seu **controller**, basta verificar se o `ModelState` está válido, da mesma forma que já deve estar fazendo.

Ressalto que também é possível fazer por atributo, mas como é apenas para um Model, não vejo necessidade.

Comment: Muito obrigado Randrade, vou adaptar o código aqui...

Answer (score 2):

Eu já tive esse problema uma vez e solucionei utilizando um IF

```
public ActionResult NomeAction(Model model)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.client_phone1) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.client_phone2))
    {
         ModelState.AddModelError("Pelo menos 1 dos 2 campos devem ser preenchidos")
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(Model model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.client_phone1) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.client_phone2))
        {                 
             ModelState.AddModelError("", "Ao menos um dos campos de telefone devem ser preenchidos.");
             return View("Create", model);
        }                        
    }
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>       
        <div class="editor-label">
             <strong>Primeiro Telefone</strong>
        </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(a => a.client_phone1)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.client_phone1) 

        <div class="editor-label">
             <strong>Segundo Telefone</strong>
        </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(a => a.client_phone2)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.client_phone2)
   </fieldset>
```

Model

```
[MaxLength(15)]    
[Display(Name = "Primeiro telefone")]
//Essa linha não é necessária
//[VerifyPhone("client_phone2")]
public string client_phone1 { get; set; }

[MaxLength(15)]
[Display(Name = "Segundo telefone")]
public string client_phone2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Eu tentei desta maneira tbm, mas o jQuery validate não mostra a mensagem, nem foi para o breakpoint.

Comment: Na sua view tem esse codigo @Html.ValidationSummary(true) ?

Comment: Não, tem a necessidade de ter esse código?

Comment: Tem esse código: @Html.AntiForgeryToken().

Comment: Ele serve para indicar onde quer que a mensagem de erro apareça, por exemplo, se deixar "true" e no ModelState você por AddModelError("Nome", "Preencha o campo nome") quando o nome não for preenchido a mensagem de erro vai aparecer ao lado do campo referente ao Nome.

Comment: Mas como as mensagens dos outros campos aparecem normalmente?

Comment: Nos outros campos você decora a propriedade no Model com [Required]?

Comment: Sim, aí o validate já cria com o htmlhelper né?

Comment: Exatamente. Você precisa que ele faça a validação desses dois campos antes do usuario enviar as informações ou pode ser depois que ele ja deu um submit?

Comment: Entendi. Acho que antes seria melhor antes, mas, no desespero que estou tanto faz kkk

Comment: Então vou editar minha resposta com uma parte do código que eu uso em minha aplicação

Comment: Beleza, muito obrigado felipe!

Comment: Funcionou Felipe, Muito Obrigado! Me salvou cara.

Comment: Não tem de quê. Disponha.