# Caixas de seleções obrigatória pelo menos 1 com Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

No **model** eu tenho:

```
[Display(Name = "Exemplo 1")]
[Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "Erro, marcar como true")]
public bool Exemplo1 { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Exemplo 2")]
public bool Exemplo2 { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Exemplo 3")]
public bool Exemplo3 { get; set; }
```

Na **view** eu tenho :

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Exemplo1, new { id = "toggle1", data_on = "Sim", data_off = "Não", data_toggle = "toggle", data_class = "fast", data_size = "mini", data_onstyle = "success", data_offstyle = "danger" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Exemplo1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Exemplo2, new { id = "toggle2", data_on = "Sim", data_off = "Não", data_toggle = "toggle", data_class = "fast", data_size = "mini", data_onstyle = "success", data_offstyle = "danger" })

@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Exemplo3, new { id = "toggle3", data_on = "Sim", data_off = "Não", data_toggle = "toggle", data_class = "fast", data_size = "mini", data_onstyle = "success", data_offstyle = "danger" })
```

Eu tenho um botão post "Create". Ao clicar botão "Create", mostrar aviso vermelho quando os 3 botões checkbox for 3 false. Devem ficar pelo menos 1 true para processar post.

Como fazer isso usando Data Annotations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você deseja é uma validação condicional. Existem várias formas de se fazer isso e algumas delas eu irei demonstrar abaixo:

#### [Interface IValidatableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

Com ela você consegue realizar algumas verificações a mais no Model. Para o seu exemplo, seria algo parecido com isso:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MeuModel : IValidatableObject
{

    [Display(Name = "Exemplo 1")]
    [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "Erro, marcar como true")]
    public bool Exemplo1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Exemplo 2")]
    public bool Exemplo2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Exemplo 3")]
    public bool Exemplo3 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Exemplo1 == false && Exemplo2 == false && Exemplo3 == false)
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Erro, marcar como true",
                         new[] { "Exemplo1", "Exemplo2", "Exemplo3" });
        }
    }
}
```

> Onde está `new[] { "Exemplo1", "Exemplo2", "Exemplo3" });` será o local que em que a mensagem de validação será exibida, ou seja, aqui: `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Exemplo1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })`. Caso queira exibir somente o **Exemplo1** não é necessário adicionar os demais.

Mais detalhes pode ser visto [nesta resposta.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152843/20615)

### [Expressive Annotations](https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations)

Este é um pacote com diversos atributos customizados para atender diversas atividades.
A sua utilização seria algo parecido com isso:

```
[Display(Name = "Exemplo 1")]
[RequiredIf("Exemplo1 == false && Exemplo2 == false && Exemplo3 == false",
ErrorMessage = "Erro, marcar como true")]
public bool Exemplo1 { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Exemplo 2")]
public bool Exemplo2 { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Exemplo 3")]
public bool Exemplo3 { get; set; }
```

Mais detalhes [nesta resposta.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37885716/4843158)

Outra opção seria realizar a verificação no controller e adicionar um erro no `ModelState` ou você mesmo desenvolver o seu próprio [CustomAttribute.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt653985.aspx)

Comment: Opção Interface IValidatableObject funcionou. Ele funciona como [Required] invés de usar [Range(typeof(bool), "true", "true", ErrorMessage = "Erro, marcar como true")] ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Com a interface você pode adicionar a validação que desejar. Verificar se é nula, se é maior que tal data, se necessita de outro valor e o que a sua mente desejar. Lembrando que não há necessidade da utilização desta se as Data Annotations atender.